# Printing value pointed by pointer within array of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

1. I am trying to print the values pointed by pointers stored inside
   ptr array. Expected output is 1,2,3,4 but the function prints the
   garbage.
2. Trying to understand how to access values within array and print
   them.

I know there's an easy way to just use double pointer to point to array and print but for learning sake trying to not use double pointer and just use pointer to whole array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t a = 1;
uint8_t b = 2;
uint8_t c = 3;
uint8_t d = 4;

uint8_t *ptr[] = {&a, &b, &c ,&d}; //Pointer is array of 4 pointer to uint8_t 


void foo(uint8_t* (*ptr)[4]) //Ptr is pointer to array of 4 pointer to uint8_t
{
    uint8_t * temp =(uint8_t*)ptr[0];
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<4;i++){
        
        printf("%d\n",*(temp+i)); //Does not print 1,2,3,4 as expected
    }
}

int main()
{
  
    foo(&ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it had the same problem as the one you've accepted. Please take a look at comments, because the solution has a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems unnecessarily complex but I guess you can do below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t a = 1;
uint8_t c = 3;
uint8_t b = 2;
uint8_t d = 4;

uint8_t *ptr[] = {&a, &b, &c ,&d};  


void foo(uint8_t* (*ptr)[4])  
{
    uint8_t ** temp =(uint8_t**)*ptr; 
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<4;i++){
     
        printf("%d\n",**(temp+i)); 
    }
}

int main()
{
  
    foo(&ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `ptr` parameter of `foo()` function is `uint8_t* (*) [4]`, which is - pointer to an array of `4` `uint8_t` pointers.

In the `foo()` function, the problem is in this statement:

```
uint8_t* temp =(uint8_t*)ptr[0];
```

From definition of the subscript operator<sup>1)</sup>, here,

```
ptr[0]  ->  *(ptr + 0) -> *(ptr) -> *ptr
```

the type of `*ptr` is `uint8_t * [4]`. So, you are initialising a `uint8_t *` type variable `temp` from `uint8_t * [4]` type variable `ptr[0]`. Hence, the initialisation of `temp` is  from an incompatible type resulting in  garbage value when accessing it. It is just that the cast is suppressing the compiler warning. Remove the cast and closely check the compiler warning.

Instead, you should initialise `temp` in `for` loop with every `i`<sup>th</sup> element of `(*ptr)` array, like this

```
uint8_t * temp = (*ptr)[i];   // type of (*ptr)[i] is uint8_t *
```

and dereferencing `temp` will give value at that location.

The type of `(*ptr)[i]` is `uint8_t *`, how? Think of it in this way -

the type of `ptr` is `uint8_t * (*) [4]`,
the type of `*ptr` is `uint8_t * [4]`, and
the type of `(*ptr)[i]` is `uint8_t *`, where `0<=i<=3`, (which is same as type of `temp` variable).

Also, you should use the format specifier macros for printing fixed width integer types<sup>2)</sup>.

> *...but for learning sake trying to not use double pointer and just use pointer to whole array...*

You don't need the `temp` pointer to print the values, you can directly print them using `ptr` pointer (parameter of `foo()` function).
You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t a = 1;
uint8_t b = 2;
uint8_t c = 3;
uint8_t d = 4;

uint8_t *ptr[] = {&a, &b, &c, &d}; //Pointer is array of 4 pointer to uint8_t 

void foo(uint8_t* (*ptr)[4]) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        /*
         * Using pointer to whole array to print the values
         */      
        printf("Using pointer to whole array : %" PRIu8 "\n", *(*ptr)[i]);

        /* 
         * Print values using temp pointer
         */
        uint8_t* temp = (*ptr)[i];
        /* 
         * temp is pointing to i'th element of (*ptr) array.
         * Dereference temp will give value at that location.
         */
        printf("Using temp pointer : %" PRIu8 "\n", *temp);

    }
}

int main (void) {
    foo (&ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Using pointer to whole array : 1
Using temp pointer : 1
Using pointer to whole array : 2
Using temp pointer : 2
Using pointer to whole array : 3
Using temp pointer : 3
Using pointer to whole array : 4
Using temp pointer : 4
```

---

1). From C11 Standard#6.5.2.1:

The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.

2). If you are using fixed width integer types (`uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `uint32_t` .... etc.) then you should use their respective conversion specifiers macros specified by language standards to print them. The `fprintf()` family function macro for unsigned decimal integer value is `PRIuN` where `N` represents the width (`8`, `16`, `32` etc..) of type. Check [macros for format specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).
Also, for these macros, you need to include `inttypes.h` header file in your program and no need to include `stdint.h` header file because `inttypes.h` header file includes `stdint.h`.

Comment: This solution is broken. Change the order of declaration of items and you will see garbage output. For instance, move `d` declaration above `a`. @Musa's solution is correct.

Comment: @Niloct Oops! my bad. Made correction in code. Check the edit.

Comment: @Vikrant Waje, My explanation for incompatible type and why getting garbage value is correct. Just made a silly mistake in the code, which I have corrected. Check the edit.